# AnyLogic: the FluidSplit block is not working well

Tags: anylogic

I have a problem with the FluidSplit block in Fluid library.

I tried to use this block to split the fluid, and put the most part of it (set with the maximun rate) into the tank, the rest will be out.

But the simulation shows the most part of it went to the out, but the rest went to the tank, which is opposite to what I want.

May I ask how to solve this problem?

I have check the documentation, it says it's a normal case, but there is no clear solution.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHea1.png)

Comment: you need to give us the properties of the split block, when you say "i want to do something" doesn't mean you are doing it right, and hiding how you did it to us, makes it impossible to help you

Comment: @Felipe Sorry for the misleading,  it's my first time posting in StackOverflow, and now I have added some details and pictures of my project, maybe you can check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

[fluidSplit Block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0nUXL.png)

Here is the properties of the fluidSplit. Select output1 as priority and setting a maxRate.

I found that the problem is caused by the priority scheme in the fluid library, but I don't know how to solve it as there are multiple storage connected to each other, which makes the priority of output2 may always greater than output1.

[Current structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7mn2.png)
Currently I am using a method that not elegant, which used fluidDispose to dispose the remaining part, and using an event to update another fluidSource's rate. I also cancelled the maxRate setting of fluidSplit and used valves instead. It works for now, but I am unsure if it will cause other issues in future.